# Best cars for drifting

Tags: engine, braking

I'm trying to find list of best cars for drifting (cheep and with left wheel), Can anyone please suggest me some cars?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You should be aware that this type of chatty discussion-type question is specifically called out in the FAQ: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask  Please try to focus on practical and answerable questions, not discussion topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks it's related on your motivation and why you want car for drifting.

For me the best solution is **Nissan Silvia S15**, it's powerful and flexible car. Adding some suspensions and other parts will allow you to win any race you want. If you are good racer.

**BMW M3 (E46)** is good one too. But remember, at first learn to leave your not such a powerful car at the ground and then think about Silvia or E36. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is top 10, if ignore the left whell

+(there is a left wheel version)

- Nissan 350Z +
- Skyline R34 GT-T
- Nissan Silvia S13
- Nissan Silvia S14
- Bmw M3 E30 Mazda +
- RX-7 (FD3S)
- Nissan 180SX/200SX +
- Nissan Silvia S15
- Bmw M3 E46 +
- Toyota Altezza